# How to float divs without overlaping on boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, overflow

I've been working with this template:  http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/google-maps , to develope this: http://www.gencat.cat/patronatmontserrat/proves/Carousel_4/itinerari_1.html and it works perfect on screen and tablets but when it resizes to phone, it's quite messy because the screen still split in two halves and it's not handy (it can't be seen the content properly) so I'd like to float the text and after the map, as if it was only one page ( but only phones).

here it is the code as far is it now:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6" id="left">

            ....all whole text and images...

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css/

```
#main, #main>.row {
    height:100%;
    text-align: justify;
}

#main>.row {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#main p {
    font-family: 'ralewayregular';
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#left {
    height:100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#map {
    width:49%;
    height:calc(100% - 0);
    position:absolute;
    right:16px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

How can I do it? Every time I try something both divs overlap each other!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to get better performance. For example

if you want to show some contents on tablets, desktop, laptop and larger screen's then use

```
<p class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"> some text</p>
```

If you want to show some text on mobile devices then use

```
<p class="visible-xs"> some text</p>
```

Using the above reference you can edit/modify your css according to your need's...

Hope this helps you...